# Knowing which dependencies to clone on a scene template?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When you create a scene template from one of your scene, you are greeted with the following editor in which one shall decide which objects to clone and which not to:

[image]

Looking closely, everything that is Unity's is marked as not to clone; everything from the project is marked as to clone.

That doesn't look quite right because most of the project dependencies are actually prefabs, thus, you would lose that template aspect that make prefabs useful.

**Question:**

How does one know what objects should (or not) be cloned in a new scene template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a template, Unity assumes that you want to modify things in the scene after it is created. This is the default behaviour mainly for convenience and you can change it from [the project settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scene-templates-settings.html).

If at least one clone option is enabled, a dialog will popup asking where to save the cloned assets when you create a new scene with the template. Prefabs will also be cloned and they will be linked to the objects in the new created scene.

If you are convinced that you want to share assets such as prefabs or textures in different new created scenes, you can disable the clone option. I guess you plan to display these same UI elements in your screenshot in different scenes, so you don't have to clone them.